# Input file como append no FormData

Tags: javascript, jquery, formdata

Como eu posso inserir imagens como `append` em um *FormData*?

Estou tentando dessa forma, mas quando uso o `console.log` para verificar a variável `dados`, o `imagens` está vazio.

```
var dados = new FormData();

$('.copiar-elemento').each(function() {
   $(this).find('input:file').each(function(index, element) {
         dados.append('cores[imagens][]', element.files[0]);
    });
});
```

Comment: Não seria `$(this).find("select[name*='tamanho']").each(function(index, element) { dados.append('cores[tamanhos][]', element.value); });` ??

Comment: Era isso mesmo, valeu! Tentei usar a mesma estrutura para fazer o mesmo com um campo file. Teria que modificar mais alguma coisa pra funcionar? Coloquei o código na pergunta.

Comment: Basta informar o terceiro parâmetro `dados.append('cores[imagens][]', element.files[0], 'imagem.jpg');` veja a [**documentação**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/FormData/append)

Comment: Mesmo com terceiro parâmetro não insere dentro do formdata. Quando uso o console.log no "dados" mostra a "imagens" vazio.

Answer (score 0):

Tente com isso:

```
var data = new FormData();

$.each($("input[type='file']")[0].files, function(i, file) {
    data.append('cores[imagens][]', file);
});

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/sua/url',
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    data : data,
    success: function(result){
        console.log(result);
    },
    error: function(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
})
```